# Creation of Spring Rest Web Services using Spring MVC for handling large request and responses

Tags: java, web-services, rest, spring-mvc

I have worked with SOAP type web-services with Axis 2 implementation where we could define contract in the form of WSDL, and that was coupled with XSD with web-services for handling the request parameters.

Where as in my current project I am going to use Spring MVC for implementation, as I am new with Spring MVC, i am unable to figure out how can I handle large requests and responses where as i have done a lot of googling and from that i got following results.

Can create WADL from Spring MVC by using some java coding and a plugin.

But i didn't get any link for a contract.

Please help me for this.

Comment: What exactly is a large request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go through http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/wa-spring3webserv/
How big is your request/response? It shouldn't matter anyway.

If it is file that you want to send as a request, you can use MultipartFile.